# How to properly implement Atooma plugin

Tags: android, atooma

I downloaded Atooma SDK, generated a skeleton and filled it with registering a single performer.
I installed my package but Atooma cannot find my plugin while doing DO part of a rule.

In logcat there is one error that is probably related:

```
Service com.atooma.AtoomaPluginService has leaked ServiceConnection com.atooma.c@41d82b88 that was originally bound here
```

Since this happens in SDK part of code I'm reluctant to make any changes there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how you start/finish this service?

Comment: In onStartCommand there is this:   if (!bound) {
   Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setClassName("com.atooma", "com.atooma.AtoomaPluginService");
   bound = bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }
  return START_STICKY;
   but AtoomaPluginService is not part of the Atooma SDK  - it's part of their application.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with including/excluding atoomasdk.jar and referencing/unreferencing AtoomaSDK project something changed and now everything works as it should!
Sorry for bothering and sorry because I cannot reproduce what I was doing to solve it...